# Phonegap + jQuery - how to output code in a div?

Tags: jquery, cordova, append

I have a Phonegap app and using jQuery "[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)".
Is there any way to put this line as a output in a div?

```
<p><a href="javascript:sound(2)"><img class="swapImageClick {src: 'soundoff.png'}" src="soundon.png /></a></p>
```

with

```
$('#div2').append ('');
```

and

```
$('#div2').html ('');
```

I had no luck because of the " " and ' '

Maybe thre is a way to split this..?
Or an other function...?
Or other chars to Mask..?

Can anybody help?

Comment: Use single quotes `'` and escape the single quotes in your string with a backslash \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid to start with. Then, you may escape quotes with `\"` or `\'`.

You can do this :

```
var html = '<p><a href="javascript:sound(2)">'
   + '<img class="swapImageClick {src: \'soundoff.png\'}" src="soundon.png">'
   + '</a></p>';
$('#div2').html (html);
```

But I may be missing something as your `class` attribute is strange. What are you trying to do with this `{src` thing ? Assuming this is just an accident, maybe you want

```
var html = '<p><a href="javascript:sound(2)">'
   + '<img class="swapImageClick" data-swap-image-click-src="soundoff.png" src="soundon.png">'
   + '</a></p>';
$('#div2').html (html);
```

As soon as you start to jungle with escaping quotes, it might be saner to start looking for another solution. For example :

```
var img = $('<img>', {
    class: 'swapImageClick',
    'data-swap-image-click-src': 'soundoff.png',
    src: 'soundon.png'
});
$('#div2').append(
     $('<p>').append(
       $('<a>').append(img)
     )
);
```

Comment: Thanks man! this is exactly what i need! The Strange looking class attribute is for jquery-swapimage plugin [link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-swapimage/)  and till now i don´t know how to Mask it right. Thanks.